# UIElement clonning

Tags: c#, wpf, clone, uielement

I'm trying to clone `UIElement`. Everything seems to be ok, but my `DependencyProperties` also copy to a new element as in:

```
var newEl = new MyElement();
```

And because one of my `DependencyProperties` is also a `UIElement` and it's already bound onto window error occurs that element is already in use. So I even can't create new element.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the only solving that I've found is to remove `DependencyProperty` and create a normal Property for my `ObservateCollection<UIElement>` and use `INotifyPropertyChanged`.